# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text', помогите подкорректировать эту ошибку

Tags: python, bs4

Выбивает непонятную ошибку.

```
def collect_data(pages_count):
     with open(f"data_{cur_date}.csv", "w") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)

        writer.writerow(
            (
                "Артикул",
                "Ссылка",
                "Цена"
            )
        )
data = []
cur_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
for page in range (1, pages_count):
  
             with open (f'data/page_{page}.html') as file: src = file.read()

             soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')

             items_card = soup.find_all('div', class_='ut2-gl__body')

             for item in items_card:
                 product_article = item.find('div',class_='ut2-gl__name').text
                 product_price = item.find('span', class_='cm-reload-98237 ty-price-update').text
                 product_url = ('href')
```

К этой строке вопросы, что это может быть?

```
product_price = item.find('span', class_='cm-reload-98237 ty-price-update').text
```

Comment: Когда функция нечего не находит, то возвращает тип NoneType.

Comment: И что мне с этим нужно сделать? Как ввести проверку что бы программа не прекращала компияцию?

Comment: Функция find не может найти тег "span" с этим классом "cm-reload-98237 ty-price-update".

Comment: Надо не проверку делать а посмотреть есть ли эти данные.

Comment: Вы что реально не поняли про что был первый комментарий ?